# HTTP POST: Headers and Payload arrive in different packets. Is this normal?

Tags: http, https, http-headers, http-post, amazon-elb

I'm troubleshooting a slowness in my web API application. The issue I find is:
- a packet arrives containing the HTTP POST with Headers only. 
- Then time passes (sometimes very long ~30 sec, sometimes milliseconds).
- another packet arrives containing the payload.

The split is always between headers and payload.

This causes the processing of the request in the app to be delayed by this interval.

Is it normal a packet will be split like that? 
Have you encountered it? 
Is it possible an AWS ELBv1 is somehow doing that?

Any direction will help - I'm totally confused...

Comment: Is it a multipart file upload?

Comment: @srikanthNutigattu nope. it's a POST with json in the content.